# How to debug a command line tool

Tags: macos, command-line, shell

I wrote a command line tool (named `cdl`) which could recognise command line parameters like `-i` (for input) and `-o` (for output). When I tired to debug it by using LLVM (`lldb cdl -i input.mp4 -o output_dir/`), I got a fault like this:

```
lldb: unrecognized option `-i input.mp4 -o test'
[the help info for lldb]
error: unknown or ambiguous option
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think it's a classic problem in shell, but I don't know how to search it.

Comment: This question may be on-topic on Stack Overflow in addition to being on-topic here — but it ***is*** on-topic here.  It is not *about* programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try `lldb -f cdl -- -i input.mp4 -o output_dir/`. The program arguments follow the `--`.

Source: `man lldb`